# How can I view a GitHub Actions build pipeline without a commit?

Tags: github, github-actions

I setup a GitHub Actions workflow in a repo by adding files under `.github/workflows/***.yml`. The YAML files' structure is very complicated. It includes many files and templates of files. It is not easy to read those files. I'd like to look at the build CI/CD pipeline in GitHub but I can't find anywhere I can view it. All I can do is to push a commit to trigger the build and look at the action associated with the commit.

Is there a way for me to review the build pipeline without pushing any commit?

My use case is that I have a monorepo in GitHub which includes a few hundred projects. Each project has different CI/CD pipelines in different environment. I'd like to find a way to easily look at what the pipeline looks like for each project in each environment. In current GitHub console, I can't find an easy way to achieve that.

Comment: No (plus padding).

Comment: in azure dev ops, at the top of the file is a line trigger:- master, set it to none and it will only trigger when you manually run it, you can edit it and run it in the portal, you can edit it and upload it in vs code but it will only run if you manually run it in the portal.

Comment: I am using github action not azure

Comment: You could try https://github.com/nektos/act; it's unclear whether this meets your requirement of _"look at the build CI/CD pipeline in GitHub"_ but it would let you _"review the build pipeline without pushing any commit"_. Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59241249/3001761.

Comment: It is not about build locally. I have added my scenarios in the post.

Comment: Then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77138256/how-can-i-view-a-github-actions-build-pipeline-without-a-commit#comment135986482_77138256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, GitHub Actions does not provide a way for you to review your GitHub workflows visually without running them. You could, however, use a tool like [yml2dot](https://github.com/lucasepe/yml2dot) or [JSON Crack](https://jsoncrack.com/) to generate visualizations of your YML workflow files.